# Как нормализовать и оптимизировать таблицу базы данных

Tags: mysql, sql

Приветствую!

Имеется `MySQL` База данных с одной таблицей типа куча. Кластеризованных либо некластеризованных индексов в ней нет - только столбцы, соответственно первичного ключа тоже нет. Таблица отражает данные о состоянии счетов клиентов и раз в сутки туда добавляются новые данные. Таблица имеет примерно такие столбцы :

> `Номер клиента` , `USD счет` , `EUR счет` , `GBP счет`.....`Дата`

Таким образом, если клиент всего один то уникальным значением будет только `Дата` если же их много то столбцов с уникальными значениями нет вообще.

Основной запрос идет на выборку по клиенту и периоду, что бы на основании его построить график для каждого счета. Выборка из такой таблицы занимает много времени а в дальнейшем, даже если число клиентов и будет незначительным, будет все дольше. Вопрос - как можно оптимизировать эту таблицу ?

Comment: А почему индексы по номеру клиента и дате не добавите?

Comment: @Visman Но ведь индекс должен быть уникальным, разве нет ? даты будут уникальными только если клиент 1 и не более. Номер же не будет уникальным вообще - каждый день добавиться новая строка с данными и тем же самым номером клиента.

Comment: Индекс не обязан быть "уникальным".

Comment: 1) Насколько помню, в MySql можно партиционировать таблицу. Вы можете ее партиционировать например по дням. 2)Номер клиента + дата должны быть уникальным, соответственно можно добавить уникальный индекс на `Номер клиента, Дата`

Comment: @lDrakonl Да, номер клиента и Дата вместе будут уникальны. Значит вопрос сводится к тому, как тогда обьявить эти столбцы как один индекс и придется ли менять текст `SQL` запроса ?

Comment: *как тогда обьявить эти столбцы как один индекс* `CREATE INDEX idx_client_date ON mytable(client,date)` *придется ли менять текст SQL запроса ?* Нет. PS. Требование уникальности на индекс можно не накладывать (или придётся смотреть приложение - вдруг оно формально допускает дублирование...).

Comment: Я настоятельно рекомендую еще посмотреть в сторону партиционирования. При большом количестве пользователей и длительном времени заполнения(например пару лет) вы можете получить очень существенный прирост производительности.

Comment: @lDrakonl Вряд ли партиционирование при наличии индекса и "одна запись для клиента в сутки" может дать такой прирост производительности, который удастся измерить.

Comment: @Akina Если я создам новый индекс(и никаких иных манипуляций) то система подзапросов SQL сама его обнаружит, поймет как его использовать и быстрее вернет данные ?

Comment: Именно так. Сервер будет использовать индекс, если, по его мнению, его использование ускорит выполнение запроса. В данном случае (как я понимаю, в основном выполняются запросы типа `SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE client = @client AND date BETWEEN @startdate AND @enddate`) показанный индекс будет использоваться. И гарантированно будет использоваться, если клиентов более полутора-двух десятков.

Comment: @Akina вы правы если из таблицы всегда будут делать ТОЛЬКО запросы по клиенту и периоду(во что я не верю). Почти наверное со временем по этой таблице захочется строить аналитику и получать информацию за период\дату без привязки к клиенту, и тогда партиции начнут творить чудеса

Comment: @Akina да описанный вами запрос полностью соответствует требуемому.  Хотелось бы конечно узнать подробнее о том как работает такой индекс но наверное в рамках одного ответа все нюансы описать не получится.

Comment: @lDrakonl Ну это извечный спор, является ли пред-оптимизация злом или благом. Я думаю, что для того, чтобы решить, рекомендовать автору партиционировать таблицу, или пока подождать с этим делом, надо бы с него вытрясти хоть какую-то информацию вроде раскладки по типовым запросам.

Comment: @lDrakonl При использовании партиций менять текст `SQL` запроса нужно ?

Comment: Думаю, для самого первичного понимания Вам будет достаточно прочитать статью **Индекс (базы данных)** на Википедии...

Comment: Текст запроса не зависит от наличия или отсутствия индексов (исключая полнотекстовый поиск), партиционирования и прочих нюансов ХРАНЕНИЯ данных.

Comment: @Akina А в MySQL есть операция аналогичная `set statistics time` в MSSQL ? Хочу измерить скорость работы до добавление индекса и после.

Comment: Выполните запрос в консоли - после итогового набора выводится время выполнения запроса. Только не забудьте добавить SQL_NO_CACHE, чтобы не получить время извлечения из кэша.

Comment: В принципе достаточно информации можно получить, выполнив `SHOW PROFILES` и `SHOW PROFILE FOR QUERY n`. Или от души покопаться в `PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA`.

Comment: @Akina В принципе разницы в скорости я пока не заметил. Однако это совершенно точно из за того, что табл пока еще мало заполнена - в ней менее 100 строк. В будущем разница наверняка проявится. Напишите пожалуйста ваши рекомендации как ответ, что бы другие люди с подобными сложностями могли его увидеть. Спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> как тогда обьявить эти столбцы как один индекс

```
CREATE INDEX idx_client_date ON mytable(client,date)
```

> придется ли менять текст SQL запроса ?

Нет.

> Если я создам новый индекс(и никаких иных манипуляций) то система подзапросов SQL сама его обнаружит, поймет как его использовать и быстрее вернет данные ?

Сервер будет использовать индекс, если, по его мнению, его использование ускорит выполнение запроса. В данном случае (как я понимаю, в основном выполняются запросы типа

```
SELECT * 
FROM mytable 
WHERE client = @client 
  AND date BETWEEN @startdate AND @enddate
```

) показанный индекс будет использоваться. И гарантированно будет использоваться, если клиентов более полутора-двух десятков.

PS. Требование уникальности на индекс можно не накладывать (или придётся смотреть приложение - вдруг оно формально допускает дублирование...).